# How to add the content of a text file to the middle of another text file

Tags: bash, sed

I tried to use sed, but I realized that it doesn't allow to charge a complete file. I am looking for a quick and neat way to:

a.txt

```
a
b
c
```

b.txt

```
d
e
f
```

And obtain

c.txt

```
a
d
e
f
b
c
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sed '/a/ r b.txt' a.txt
a
d
e
f
b
c
```

The condition `/a/` looks for a line containing `a`.  On such a line, the command `r b.txt` is executed which reads the file `b.txt`.

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Comment: @je_b _"it didn't work."_  In order to help, I need more information. When you ran the command, how did the output differ from what I show above?  Did the command produce an error message?  If so, what was it?

Comment: Finally worked when an space is added after the second / . Thank you

Comment: @je_b OK.  Although it works fine for me either way, I added that space to the answer.